# Scale dimensions in a physics simulation

Tags: java, applet, scale, physics, game-physics

I need some help here with a physics simulation in java I'm writing. The simulation is about the free fall of a body. I'm using java and I don't use any third-party library.

I have an applet (1400px wide, 700px high) and a sprite (which is oval) falling down. The gravity is set to 10 m/s². I apply second Newton's Law to my oval sprite, and I use RK4 algorithm to compute the x an y coordinates of my sprite over time.

This all works fine...Except that I don't know how to scale the dimensions I use in my simulation.

For example, I would like 1px to represent 1cm (both width and height). So that my 1400px*700px applet dimensions will represent 14m*7m in real. I used

> Graphics2D.scale()

method but it does't seem to work. I also thought to change the gravity but this seems not appropriate for me...

Could someone tell me a proper way to scale my dimensions?

Comment: You have 100 pixels per meter.  Calculate your x and y position in meters, then multiply x by 100 and y by 100 to plot.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc If I do what you suggest, I will need an applet of 14m*7m dimensions, which can't fit any screen. I'm I wrong? (Or perhaps I just don't get what you mean)...

Answer (score 0):

You have a 1400 x 700 pixel applet drawing area.

You have a 14 x 7 meter physics area.

In order to scale from meters to pixels, you have to use a scaling factor.

```
1400 pixels / 14 meters = 100 pixels per meter.
700 pixels / 7 meters = 100 pixels per meter.
```

So far so good.  If you had two different scaling factors, your drawing area would be distorted.

Let's assume that the oval started at (0, 0).

So we calculate the first position of the oval.  Let's assume the first calculated position is

```
x = 2.45
y = 3.83
```

So, using the scaling factor we came up with:

```
pixel x = 2.45 meters x 100 pixels per meter = 245 pixels.
pixel y = 3.83 meters x 100 pixels per meter = 383 pixels.
```

Our physics area has increasing x to the right and increasing y down.  Fortunately, our drawing area has increasing x to the right and increasing y down.

So, we don't have to worry about changing signs.

Draw the oval at (245, 383).

Calculate next x, y position and repeat.